# QGIS globe map - label distortion

Tags: qgis, labeling, globe

I have created an azimuth orthographic projection map (basically a globe, I've used this custom CRS: `+proj=ortho +lat_0=51.470129 +lon_0=-0.452751 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs` with QGIS 3.4.4. The labels are flat, as you would expect for readability purpose. Does anybody know if it's possible to have the labels following the earth surface curvature instead, like if it was an actual picture of a physical globe?

If it's not possible with QGIS, how about other software programs?